# Is there a way to see all installed service workers in browsers in iOS or Andorid and/or manually clear them?

Tags: mobile, service-worker

In desktop I can go to chrome://serviceworker-internals/ to see all installed service workers in my chrome browsers and optionally unregister manually.
Is there any similar feature available in Chrome or Safari on iOS or Android devices?

Given that in Mobile devices, browser is always running in background and service workers can be active even if the pages are not open, it's important to see what SWs are potentially running on my device.

Comment: I just published a new version of a website, for the life of me i can't find a way to remove the service worker so the MOBILE browser (chrome, brave) will load the new version.